# @XmlElement(name = "", required = true) not working with springboot validator

Tags: spring-boot, validation, jaxb

Initially I had an old xsd and from that I generated classes using xjc. I am trying to use JaxB annotation based validation but it seems Validation is ignoring required. Some of the xml nodes are mandatory but as validator is not using required marked in @XMLElement so object is going to backend system and then it fails.

@XmlElement(name = "", required = true)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbAnnotationModule() {
        return new JaxbAnnotationModule();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory()));
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Validation done using

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;
...Some code...
Set<ConstraintViolation<Request>> violations = validator.validate(request);
```